# Defining aliases in Cygwin under Windows

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to define some aliases in cygwin, but with no success. I am doing so like this at the end of the `.bashrc` file.

```
alias foo='pwd'
```

I have tried to add this line in a `.bashrc` file in both inside the `home` folder of cygwin and in the home folder for the Windows user I am on `C:\Users\Nuno\`. In both cases I have just appended this line to a copy of the `/etc/skel/.bashrc` file. In either cases, it didn't work.

I had this working before. I had to reinstall Cygwin and ever since it never worked properly again. I have removed all files (or at least think so, when doing the reinstallation). I have also noticed that in the first install (when it was working) cygwin already was creating .bash files in the `home` folder. Now, it doesn't.

I am on a machine running Windows 7.

**EDIT**: My cygwin home folder is set to the Windows home folder `C:\Users\Nuno\`. I have placed what I think is a valid `.bashrc` file there, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you end up when you execute `cd`, because that location is your home dir and that's where .bashrc should live.

Comment: already edited the question to answer that. please take a look. thanks.

Comment: Odd... what's the output of `echo $HOME` ?

Comment: it's `/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator` (my actual username is Administrator, not Nuno as I as saying before, but that shouldn't be an issue I think).

Comment: I never tried changing the default location of the home dir, which is `cygwin-installdir/home/username` and I just tested, changing the default .bashrc that's copied in there by the installer works, so I think you slightly messed up your installation somehow...  Also on Win7 btw.

Comment: I think that's the case.. I would guess something about the registry, but just guessing really and no idea how to fix that. Thanks for your help, though. Please let me know if you think of something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26964/discussion-between-fvu-and-nunos)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As me_and already explained what's going on I just want to add a workaround should you for whatever reason not be able or willing to remove Windows' HOME environment variable.

Normally the shortcut for Cygwin executes

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

Instead you can create a batchfile with the following content and start that:

```
@echo off
set HOME=
start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

That will start a a Cygwin windows whose home directory settings are not overridden by a Windows environment variable.

Comment: Your awesome, this also worked for git bash (enabling heroku)  `@echo off
set HOME=
start C:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe --cd-to-home`

Answer (score 12):

Your `.bashrc` file will be loaded from wherever Cygwin Bash thinks your home directory is when it starts. You've mentioned in your edit that you've changed your home directory, but not how, so it's possible you've made a mistake there.

Cygwin will load your home directory from one of two places, and if they differ it can cause problems:

- The `HOME` environment variable.  This will be picked up from however you launch Cygwin, so normally from Windows itself. You can see what environment variables you have defined by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>, going to "Advanced system settings", "Environment Variables…". If "HOME" is in either "User variables" or "System variables", delete it – it's unnecessary and only causes problems.
- Cygwin's `/etc/passwd` file (normally `C:\Cygwin\etc\passwd` from Windows). This will have a number of lines containing details of each user on the system; the seventh `:` separated field is the home directory. You can tell which user it's looking at by running `whoami` from a Cygwin bash shell.

If `whoami` reports `nunos`, you should have a line in Cygwin's `/etc/passwd` that looks something like the following:

```
nunos:unused:1001:513:U-System\nunos:S-1-2-34-567890-123456-7890123-1001:/home/nunos:/bin/bash
```

It's that `/home/nunos` that's important; if it's something different you should probably reset it to that, at which point you want to use the `.bashrc` in Cygwin's `/home/nunos/`.

You should also be very wary of directories that contain spaces for this. `C:\Users\nunos` *should* be fine, but beware in particular `C:\Documents and Settings\nunos`, which just won't work with Cygwin.

Comment: +1, good explanation, but after testing on my system I can confirm that if the homedir is set to the user's dir in c:\users ( `/cygdrive/c/Users/nunos` in cygwin-speak) .bashrc isn't picked up.  A small request: can you explain why erasing Windows' setting of `HOME` is a safe thing to do?

Comment: @fvu: Very few Windows programs use environment variables at all, and those that do will almost certainly have a sensible default. Windows itself certainly makes no use of `HOME`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue,  where the aliases added to ~/.bashrc didn't work.
It seems that, for some reason, the ~/.bashrc was not executed when launching the console.

I stumbled upon a [response](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-07/msg01063.html) that fixes the issues

So, you need to create a .bash_profile file. This one seems to be the default script, and put this code in it, to ensure that the .bashrc is executed.

```
# ~/.bash_profile: executed by bash for login shells.

if [ -e /etc/bash.bashrc ] ; then
 source /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

if [ -e ~/.bashrc ] ; then
 source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

That works for me, just make sure that .bash_profile is executable. (chmod +x ~/.bash_profile)

Comment: This might be obvious, but just in case for those for which it is not (e.g. me) - I was attempting this with no success, restarted cygwin, and then it worked. Forgot that the script is loaded on launch.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really quick and dirty way to do it, but it works fine for *most* things!

Let's say you want to always run 'ls --color' instead of just 'ls'. Instead of messing around with .bashrc stuff, you can create a simple .bat file that essentially bootlegs the original ls command.

Here's what I did:

```
cd /bin
echo ls2.exe %* --color > lsNew.bat
mv ls.exe ls2.exe
mv lsNew.bat ls.bat
```

So now, whenever you type in ls from CMD, you actually are calling ls.bat, which in turn calls ls2.exe --color, the original ls command with the --color flag, along with the rest of the arguments, which are nicely passed through %*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I was using ConEmu to run my console. I had to go into settings and change the settings from this :

> set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\Programs\Cygwin\bin\sh.exe --login -i -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\Programs\Cygwin\Cygwin.ico"

to this:

> set HOME= & set CHERE_INVOKING=1 &
>   %ConEmuDrive%\Programs\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
>   -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\Programs\Cygwin\Cygwin.ico"

Then it would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It works as explained from cygwin:

Create a file ".profile" in your windows home dir. This will load every time when you start cygwin.

You can edit the file with your alias or you can source the .bashrc.

If you'll source, insert "source .bashrc" and save .bashrc also in your windows home dir.
Now you can start editing the .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me On windows 10 with Cygwin64. Don't worry "kubectl" is just the program that I want to run when I type "k". restart Cygwin terminal after the change.

Smith@NB-Smith-3 ~  echo "alias k=C:/Users/Smith/kube/kubectl" >> $HOME/.bash_profile

changes this file
C:\cygwin64\home\Smith.bash_profile

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem is why the path not is correct, the path correct is: D:\C++\cygwin\home\USER_WINDOWS.bash_profile