# Referencing the HOME path in Cygwin aliases

Tags: cygwin, bash

I use a lot of aliases in my Cygwin .bash_profile as a way to cd to various lengthy network drives. I am also modifying this .bash_profile file frequently as new drives need to be accessed.

I'm trying to create an alias that will open my .bash_profile in a text editor and allow me to quickly edit it from anywhere. Let's use the following as an example:

```
alias editbash='subl ~/.bash_profile'
```

"subl" is another alias for the path to my Sublime Text executable.. this works fine.

My main issue is that when I execute this alias, it attempts to open a file at the following path:

```
C:\home\username\.bash_profile
```

... instead of...

```
C:\cygwin\home\username\.bash_profile
```

I have attempted to modify this alias to use the following:

```
alias editbash='subl /cygwin/home/username/.bash_profile'
```

This works, but only if I'm currently viewing something in my C: drive, which I am often not.

How can I update this alias to always reference my *Cygwin user* home directory, rather than the Windows home directory? Or, if it's easier, how can I always reference the C: drive in my latter example?

Comment: I think something has happened with your environment, what does `echo $HOME` give you? Should be something like /home/username , there may be a windows HOME environment variable causing problems. [See the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641346/defining-aliases-in-cygwin-under-windows?rq=1)

Comment: 'echo $HOME' gives me '/home/username'.

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the home directory as /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/username

That should solve the problem.

Comment: If I use the following path: '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/username', it attempts to open my .bash_profile file at the following path in Windows: C:\cygdrive\c\cygwin\home\username\.bash_profile.

Obviously, C:\cygdrive isn't a real directory on my C: drive. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit you home variable in the /etc/passwd file. Use `pwd` to find out where you are. Then the tilde can point where you actually want it to.

Answer (score 0):

The shellslash option seemed worth a try in spite of the warnings about it breaking things.

So before that, I tried a few different aliases in .bashrc - AND ONE SIMPLE THING WORKED by prepending a backslash:

```
alias vib='vi "\$HOME/.bashrc"'
```

... and works just as I wanted - Thanks!