# Set aliases in bash.bashrc

Tags: python, bash, cygwin, alias

When I try to set aliases, I get two different results using two different methods.  I'm using cygwin.

METHOD 1:

In cygwin I execute the following:

`alias python='/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe'`

`python <name of python file>`

...and it runs just fine, as expected

METHOD 2:

In my bash.bashrc file I add the following line:

`alias python='/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe'`

`python <name of python file>`

...and I get the following error:

`:no such file or directoryython.exe`

Just two questions:
What is the difference between these two methods? 
Why is one causing and error and one is not?  Thanks <3

Comment: Well the answer is in your post itself. It is not able to find the path that you have given

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641346/defining-aliases-in-cygwin-under-windows
check this QA

Answer (score 0):

The error indicate that the `bash.bashrc` file was not loaded.

Check these:

1. The bashrc filename is usually `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile` and it's in the user's home directory. Or it should exists as `/etc/bash.bashrc`.
2. The file is not loaded automatically, restart the shell to load it.

Comment: I think OP has done it. Otherwise he would have got command not found error

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal, I don't think so. I suspect the OP ran another `alias`, and the bashrc file was not loaded.

Comment: :no such file or directoryython.exe error will be given when ailas is loaded correctly.

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal, `alias python='/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe'`, if this was executed, it should work as expected. I think OP ran something like this: `alias python=directoryython.exe` in shell.

Comment: did some researched on it. Cygwin alias work little differenlty. It refers to home of Windows OS

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal, OP is using `bash.bashrc`, not `.bashrc`. `bash.bashrc` should be in `/etc`, `.bashrc` should be in `$HOME` (or `~`).

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal, echoing `$HOME`, `~` correctly show home directory: (`/cygdrive/c/Users/falsetru` for me, which is same windows home directory basically). http://i.imgur.com/RkZ3R2C.png

Answer (score 0):

See how this error is all confused looking?

```
:no such file or directoryython.exe
```

Your `bash.bashrc` file has DOS line endings. Go fix that.